# Creating a HighChart from database

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, bar-chart

I'm really new to HighChart and I've tried some examples but still unsure. I'm trying to make a weekly/monthly basic bar chart to show the activity of the sensors which is in mysql database. X-axis is the number of value at each location from the table sensor and Y-axis is the days (Monday-Sunday).

This is my database tables

```
sensor:
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| id        | time                | value |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+
| 12341     | 2015-08-17 10:16:41 |   1   |
| 12341     | 2015-08-17 10:17:29 |   1   |
| 12342     | 2015-08-17 10:18:06 |   1   |
| 12343     | 2015-08-17 13:28:55 |   1   |
| 12344     | 2015-08-17 13:29:49 |   1   |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+

data:
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+
| id        | description        | location    |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+
| 12341     |       Sensor       | Location1   |
| 12342     |       Sensor       | Location2   |
| 12343     |       Sensor       | Location3   |
| 12344     |       Sensor       | Location4   |   |
+-----------+--------------------+-------------+
```

I have done a hardcoded bar chart but have no idea for the next steps.

highchart.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Information</title>
   <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>  
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto">    </div>
<script language="JavaScript">


$(document).ready(function() {  
   var chart = {
      type: 'bar'
   };
   var title = {
      text: 'Activities of the Elderly'   
   };
   var subtitle = {
      text: 'Testing'  
   };
   var xAxis = {
      categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
      title: {
         text: null
      }
   };
   var yAxis = {
      min: 0,
      title: {
         text: 'No. of times movement detected',
         align: 'high'
      },
      labels: {
         overflow: 'justify'
      }
   };
   var tooltip = {
      valueSuffix: 'times'
   };
   var plotOptions = {
      bar: {
         dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
           }
      }
   };

// Load the fonts
Highcharts.createElement('link', {
   href: '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,700',
   rel: 'stylesheet',
   type: 'text/css'
}, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);

// Add the background image to the container
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'getContainer', function (proceed) {
   proceed.call(this);
   this.container.style.background = 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sand.png)';
});


Highcharts.theme = {
   colors: ["#f45b5b", "#8085e9", "#8d4654", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
  "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
   chart: {
      backgroundColor: null,
      style: {
         fontFamily: "Signika, serif"
      }
   },
   title: {
      style: {
         color: 'black',
         fontSize: '16px',
         fontWeight: 'bold'
      }    
   },
   subtitle: {
    style: {
         color: 'black'
      }
   },
   tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0
   },
   legend: {
      itemStyle: {
         fontWeight: 'bold',
         fontSize: '13px'
      }
   },
   xAxis: {
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#6e6e70'
         }
      }
   },
   yAxis: {
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#6e6e70'
         }
      }
   },
   plotOptions: {
      series: {
         shadow: true
      },
      candlestick: {
         lineColor: '#404048'
      },
      map: {
         shadow: false
      }
   },

   // Highstock specific
   navigator: {
      xAxis: {
         gridLineColor: '#D0D0D8'
      }
   },
   rangeSelector: {
      buttonTheme: {
         fill: 'white',
         stroke: '#C0C0C8',
     'stroke-width': 1,
         states: {
            select: {
               fill: '#D0D0D8'
            }
         }
      }
   },
   scrollbar: {
      trackBorderColor: '#C0C0C8'
   },

   // General
   background2: '#E0E0E8'

};

// Apply the theme
Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);


<?php
mysql_connect ("server","user","password") or die ('Cannot connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("dbtable") or die ('Cannot connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from sensor") or die ('Query is invalid: ' .   mysql_error());

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $date['data'][] = $r['date'];
   $value['data'][] = $r['value'];

}
$result = array();
array_push($result,$date);
array_push($result,$value);

echo json_encode($result); 
?>


   var legend = {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      x: -40,
      y: 100,
      floating: true,
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme &&         Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
      shadow: true
   };
   var credits = {
      enabled: false
   };

   var series= [{
            name: 'Kitchen',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Toilet',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'LivingRoom',
            data: [973, 914, 404, 732, 34]      
        }, {
            name: 'BedRoom',
            data: [973, 914, 404, 732, 34]
    }
   ]; 



   var json = {};   
   json.chart = chart; 
   json.title = title;   
   json.subtitle = subtitle; 
   json.tooltip = tooltip;
   json.xAxis = xAxis;
   json.yAxis = yAxis;  
   json.series = series;
   json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
   json.legend = legend;
   json.credits = credits;
   $('#container').highcharts(json);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your query response, in which format you are fetching data from DB?

Comment: in Json? the response is something like this ' [["2015-09-29 15:15:49","2015-09-29 12:40:01","2015-09-29 10:09:12","2015-10-01 17:22:38",
"2015-10-01 16:39:41","2015-10-01 13:39:00","2015-10-01 13:35:45","2015-10-01 13:35:24",
"2015-09-30 14:40:44","2015-09-30 11:21:08","2015-09-30 11:17:20","2015-09-30 09:45:26",
"2015-09-30 09:44:20","2015-09-29 17:41:45","2015-09-29 17:41:43","2015-09-29 17:41:43",
"2015-09-29 17:41:42","2015-09-29 17:41:39","2015-09-29 17:38:36","2015-09-29 16:48:56"],
["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]]'

Comment: So if you need daily,weekly column graph your data should be grouped daily or weekly. mean you have multiple entries for same day, instead get total value for each day and return in json.

Comment: At the beginning you should use timestamps instead of date strings. To do this you can use strtotime in your PHP. Values also should be numbers.

Comment: @SebastianBochan timestamps? But in database, it's datetime format, so does it affect? the values are numbers..

Comment: After get your data from database you can convert that to timestamps by strtotime.